# Google App Script. Filtering data base on date

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-apps-script, filter, format

[A snippet of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq81W.png)I am trying to filter a list of duty rooster base on date and send out reminders to assigned staff.

I do not encounter any error when I run the script but no mail get sent out.

Below is the block of code used.

```
// Declaring variables

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get active spreadsheet
var schedule = ss.getSheetByName("Duties & Timelines"); // Get the schedule sheet

function sendReminderEmail() {

  var currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");

  var data = schedule.getRange("A:J").getValues();
  
  const due = schedule.getRange("A:J").getValues().filter(function (row) {
    var cell = schedule.getRange("I2:I");
    cell.setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd');
    return cell == currentDate;
  }); // Filter to get row with reports that are due

  due.forEach(function(item) {


    // Set the email details
    const recipientEmail = "example@gmail.com";
    const subject = "Monthly Reminder";
    const body = "This is your monthly reminder.";



    // Send the email
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: recipientEmail,
      subject: subject,
      body: body
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: In `filter` of your script, I think that the values of `cell, currentDate` are Class Rnage object and string value, respectively. By this, `cell == currentDate` is always false. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `I do not encounter any error when I run the script but no mail get sent out.`. But, even when this is resolved, I think that in `forEach` function, I'm worried that the situation in which the value of `item` is not used might be the next issue. So, can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike What I am expecting is for the script to iterate and filter out tasks/ duties due and send a reminder to just the employees these tasks have been assigned to via email

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `What I am expecting is for the script to iterate and filter out tasks/ duties due and send a reminder to just the employees these tasks have been assigned to via email`, unfortunately, I cannot imagine your situation. I think that in this case, in order to modify your script, it is required to know the situation of your Spreadsheet. Can you provide more information to understand your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike I have added an image of the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Date().valueOf() to get the date at 0000;

```
function sendReminderEmail() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Duties & Timelines");
 var vs = schedule.getRange("A2:J"+ sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
 const dt = new Date();
 const dv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//date at midnight
 const due = vs.filter(row => {
    let d = new Date(r[8]);
    let date = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();//date at midnight
    return d == dv;
  }).filter(e => e); 
 due.forEach(function(item) {
   const recipientEmail = "example@gmail.com";
    const subject = "Monthly Reminder";
    const body = "This is your monthly reminder.";
   MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: recipientEmail,
      subject: subject,
      body: body
    });
  })
}
```

- [new Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)